# absolute positioning not working with XHTML?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I'm trying to position a DIV with absolute positioning, however it appears that with XHTML DOCTYPE it doesn't work. In the following example, the red square appears at top-left, instead of being somewhere in the middle of the screen :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="screen,projection" />
<style type="text/css">

body { background-color: silver; }
div
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
div#one
{
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
top:520;
left: 220; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>
This is some text this is some text this is some.
</h1>
<div id="one"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If appears that if I replace the DOCTYPE to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

It will work correctly, however I would like to follow XHTML doctype.
Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `px` to your `top` and `left` properties:

```
top: 520px;
left: 220px
```

With the XHTML doctype (or more precisely: [Standards Mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#modes)), the browser will not assume that you mean `px` if you do not explicitly state it, in contrast to Quirks Mode.

Comment: good point, that is probably the reason. My answer is seems like a smart thing to do, but your answer is likely the ACTUAL reason of the issue.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this isn't because the Doctype says "XHTML", it just isn't one considered to be a relic from beyond the dawn of time (like HTML 4.01 Transitional with the URI missing). Also worth pointing out that using markup and CSS validators is a really good idea (and would pick up the missing units in the CSS).

Comment: @David Dorward: Good points. If I remember correctly, it's a case of Quirks mode (being triggered by that old doctype) treating unitless measurements as `px` values.

Answer (score 1):

In XHTML absolute positioned elements with no content become "invisible" because they get width 0 and height 0. Try adding content to your div#one or try the following CSS

```
div#one
{
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
top:520px;
left: 220px; 
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately for your answer, he's already giving the `div` a `width` and `height` see: `div { width: 100px; height: 100px }`

Comment: True, I realised later that thirtydot's answer is the correct one.