# absolute div within another div is not taking the absolute position

Tags: css

I have the following divs. The style elements will be transferred to a stylesheet as soon as i get the right combination of style elements.

I am trying to get the last div to have an absolute position relative to the div within which it exists ("one"). But it is dropping to the bottom of div "one" as though it were relative. What am i doing wrong?

```
<div id="one" style = "position: relative; width: 900px; height: 250px;">
   <% (5 .. 14).each do |s| %>
      <div style="position: relative; margin-left: 150px;"><%= @name[s] %></div>
   <% end %>
   <div style = "position: absolute; top: 100; left: 10;">Top Six</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The last `<div>` is missing units on the `top` and `left` attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'px' to your top and left attributes:

```
<div style = "position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 10px;">Top Six</div>
```

Comment: oh man. Can't believe i missed that. It's all in the details :=]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> What am i doing wrong?

You need to add `px` to your `left` and `top` properties.

See this similar question I answered for an explanation of why:
[absolute positioning not working with XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932480/absolute-positioning-not-working-with-xhtml/4932498#4932498) (particularly the comments)